# Will Embarcadero RadPHP XE2 scale to an e-commerce site?

Tags: ide, e-commerce, radphp, rpcl

In a nutshell: is RadPHP a toy? or can you build real web sites, such as a e-commerce/shopping carts app that will:

1. Support 100s of simultaneous users on a reasonably good web server, like any other PHP app

   - my specific concern is the RPCL library might be bloated and inefficient
2. Be easy to assign the CSS hooks and integrate CSS files supplied by designers
3. Be as easy as 'plain' PHP programming is to talk to external sites such as payment gateways
4. Easily integrate third party components; Javascript and PHP e.g. Lightbox, eg CKEditor.

I am coming from a Delphi background, not PHP, so please excuse my ignorance and trouble at evaluating RadPHP XE2's potential as an easier way to transition to web development without sacrificing potential to scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It has a demo app created for oscommerce the well known open source e-commerce app.
2. Yes
3. No appearent barrier.
4. It already has components integrating 3rd party stuff such as zend, qooxdoo, jquery etc..

I'm also coming from delphi background with almost no php. Currently I'm developing a prado framework based ERP application using eclipse as ide. On my leisure time I'm toying with radphp, and I think we could have used it as well as the eclipse-prado kit but I'm in no place to make the decision. In my experience radphp is developing well into form. The first releases / versions were really sluggish. But XE2 looks solid. If vcl for php is fine tuned for performance in the future releases, radphp will have better days.